# Issue to get jReject working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get [jReject](http://jreject.turnwheel.com) working on my website http://goo.gl/YbW2xb but can't get it working for some reason.
Here is what I did, can you please tell me what is missing / what I did wrong? I suspect this comes from the `<script>` part.

1. call this in my `<head>` tag: jquery.reject.css and jquery.browser.min.js and jquery.reject.js

2 added this just before `</head>`

```
  <script>
$.reject({  
        reject: { all: true }, // Reject all renderers for demo  
        header: 'Your browser is not supported here', // Header Text  
        paragraph1: 'You are currently using an unsupported browser', // Paragraph 1  
        paragraph2: 'Please install one of the many optional browsers below to proceed',  
        closeMessage: 'Close this window at your own demise!' // Message below close window link  
    }); // Customized Text  

    return false;  
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid. Why do you have the final `return false; });`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It comes from #Demo3 on http://jreject.turnwheel.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not calling your script, at least you can simple call dom ready function.
Also you need to call jquery before this function

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.reject({  
        reject: { all: true }, // Reject all renderers for demo  
        header: 'Your browser is not supported here', // Header Text  
        paragraph1: 'You are currently using an unsupported browser', // Paragraph 1  
        paragraph2: 'Please install one of the many optional browsers below to proceed',  
        closeMessage: 'Close this window at your own demise!' // Message below close window link  
    }); // Customized Text  

    return false;  
});
```

Comment: did you copy paste jquery link too, because if you have it already and if you copied my post too, you must have 2 jquery include which causes a confliction

Comment: No I did not as I already have it (you can view the full code by accessing the source code of the page). Tks

Comment: try to add your script at the end of body tag

Comment: also at the end of your script you have extra close bracelets }); delete this